# Master, Partials Rendering and Javascript Calls

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'd like to understand the order of things that occur once there is a master page, a partial and some javascript code.

Let's say I have a Master page with scripts:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" ... %>

<head>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server" />
    // header stuff
</head>

<body>
// Html stuff here

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function foo () {
};
</script>
```

Now I have  a page, Index.aspx, that inherits from this Master page and has this in it:

```
<script type="text/javascipt">
    foo();
</script>
```

What happens is I get `"foo() is not defined"` error message in my chrome's console, while if I take the script chunk from the Master page and move it to its header, everything works fine.

So my questions are -

1. what is the order of things, and what happens first ?
   Does the Index.aspx rendering occur before the Master page fully loads so the Index.aspx page does not yet know what is defined on the bottom of the Master page ? (and it's fine if it's on the top?) 
   I believe the answer is yes to this one.
2. The more puzzling question - if the rendering of the Master page is not yet fully finished on the server side, how is javascript from the Index.aspx page called? 
   To phrase this equivalently - If I have an A page rendering B rendering C rendering (and so forth), is the first javascript that's gonna get called is the one on C's page (or the last one being called)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit different. At first everything, i.e. the page itself and all master pages it uses, is rendered on a server to produce an HTML markup. Then this markup is sent to the client, where it is displayed by the browser. Also on the client side all javascript is executed. So the file in which the javascript is defined (page A, page B, page C, Master page) does not really matter, as far as javascript execution goes. However what does matter is the order in which javascript chunks appear in the final page.

Consider the example. The master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" ... %>

<head>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server" />
    // header stuff
</head>

<body>
    // Html stuff here
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="BodyContent" runat="server" />
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function foo () {
    };
</script>
```

And now the child page:

```
<%@ Page Master="... %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascipt">
        foo();
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

In this layout in the final page you will have the following order of the javascript blocks:

```
<script type="text/javascipt">
    foo();
</script>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
     function foo () {
    };
</script>
```

So the call to the `foo` happens before it is defined, which results into the error you are getting. This is what happening in your case I believe.

However if you move the js block in master to the head, in the resulting HTML blocks are getting reversed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function foo () {
    };
</script>
...
<script type="text/javascipt">
    foo();
</script>
```

`foo` is defined at first, and called after, which is fine.

Hope this clarifies the process.

Answer (score 0):

The function must appear before being called. So:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function foo () {
    };
</script>
```

Must appear before

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    foo();
</script>
```

Also, foo() will never run because you have a spelling mistake in the script type, missing the 'r' in javascript.

If you have functions defined within your masterpage and wish to call them from inherited pages, you could add a script placeholder as so:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" ... %>
<html>
    <head>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="BodyContent" runat="server" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function foo () {
            };
        </script>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ScriptContent" runat="server" />
    </body>
</html>
```